# js post data to rails & refreshing view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, post, reload

I have a problem (oh no). 
With rails I'm showing table which is sortable, I move the line, ajax posts data (which line to where) to rails controller, which saves data to DB (render :nothing => true).

Now I wish to reload the page as new calculation should occur. 
If I use reload in js (success: window.location.reload();) page reloads but with old data. I used also delay (setTimeout(,.., 1000)) without success.

It seems as data is not yet in DB.

How can I reload in rails controller where the data was POST.
Or maybe other solution.

LP dejan

Comment: Where do you use the reload? If the data is coming from rails side, that should work, unless you're not waiting Ajax call to be finished. This code should be in Ajax callback (After the controller processed, reload the page)

Comment: Are you able refresh the page and see changes? I am just wonder there is a bug and when you refresh it is resorting the table.

Comment: Well, when all conditions are met js (Coffeescript) post data :           $.ajax(
            type: 'POST'
            url: '/cashflow/update_row_order'
            dataType: 'json'
            data: ndata
           success: document.location.reload() # too slow
          )

Comment: Well, when all conditions are met js (Coffeescript) post data :           <code>$.ajax(
            type: 'POST'
            url: '/cashflow/update_row_order'
            dataType: 'json'
            data: ndata
           success: document.location.reload() # too slow
          ) </code>  <br/>then to  <br/>   <code> def update_row_order
    if buen_params[:bid] != "0"
      @bthing = current_user.taccount.buens.real.active.find(buen_params[:bid])
      @bthing.update_attribute(:widate1, buen_params[:nwidate1])
      @bthing.save!
    end
    render nothing: true 
  end</code>

Answer (score 1):

I did it with your help. THX.

so in JS code which POST I had to change dataType to 'script'

```
  $.ajax(
      type: 'POST'
      url: '/x/update_row_order'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: ndata

  )
```

then as suggested in action

```
def update_row_order
  # ndata saved in model
  render js inline: "location.reload();"
end
```

as window.location.reload(); didn't work 
And that's it. THX again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload page, then create a javascript file in your views and write reload code in the view file.

In your controller_name#action_name

```
def action_name 
 format.js 
end
```

In your view (action_name.js) file, just write:

> `window.location.reload();`

It works.

Comment: Thx all for prompt reply. I'll try and let you know if problem is solved.

Comment: sorry, but doesn't work. Rendering is performed bu still doesn't reload the page. even if I enter in controller format.html { redirect_to cashflow_tliquidity_path } in backend it is visible that rails is producing page but in browser there is no change.